# how to make widgets in c# for desktops apps

Tags: c#, for-loop, widget, desktop-application

I am doing a desktop application for calendars,sticky notes,diary,todolist,reminders and sending and receiving e-mail. I want to make a widget for all this.Wiget should also display messages if new mail is received. but i dont know from where to start making a widget.let me know is there are some controls in visual studio to make widgets or not.From where is should start.

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far to maximize the chance that someone will help you. In particular a web search should help you find resources on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for WPF. It's a steep learning curve, but you'll be able to virtually make any app you want. It supports real transparency, you can design the app the way you want without borders. You're looking for `Window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None`. Start from here.

Note that it won't be a 'widget' as the clock widget in Windows 7 for example. You'll make a normal desktop app (.exe) but with special functionality.

Bottom line, you can do that (and more) in WPF but you'll want to be comfortable around it first.